# How to convert the curl command to a python api? I tried converting but it responds with 400 bad request

Tags: python, api, deep-learning

I have converted the curl command into the python code using this [website](https://curl.trillworks.com/) but the code doesn't seem to work.

**Curl Command**

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8881/models/aak/v1/predict" -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F "data={\"key\": \"Filename\"};type=application/json" -F "Filename=@img.png"
```

**Python Code**

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}

files = {
    'data': (None, '{"key": "Filename"};type'),
    'Filename': ('img.png', open('img.png', 'rb')),
}

response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8881/models/aak/v1/predict', headers=headers, files=files)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569). In summary, asking us to hurry up makes it even _less likely_ that you get a (good) answer.

Comment: What error are you getting? I'm not sure you are specifying the correct image. Using [Websites Like These](https://curl.trillworks.com/) usually just mask the problem.

Comment: I have used the website mentioned @EdekiOkoh and the code written above is taken from the same site but it still gives an error.

Comment: I have a submission of my final year project next week that is why i mentioned urgent @AdrianW

Comment: If you are serious about getting an answer please [read through this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and reformat your question. Currently it is too broad to answer

Comment: Is it any better now? @EdekiOkoh This is my first time using stack overflow to ask a question.

Comment: What is the error response is showing?

Comment: 400 Bad request. The browser sent a request that this server  could not understand @therealJoeT

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more background to the situation in general, I'm assuming your running some type of flask ML server. Also, how your running your script.  I'm assuming you have everything else properly configured and the correct working directory set.

I'm not one hundred percent certain of what the server is expecting but I'll give it a shot

Lets break down the message being sent:

**api url** - http://127.0.0.1:8881/models/aak/v1/predict

**method** - post

**body/json** - {"Key": "Filename"}

**file/image** - image.png

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8881/models/aak/v1/predict'
json_data = {"Key": "Filename"}

file = {
         'data': (None, json.dumps(json_data), 'application/json'),
         'file': (file_name, open('image.png', 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
}

r = requests.post{url, files=file}

print(r.status_code) # should be 200 or you can access attributes of r if something else should be returned
```

Note - You may need to set the header as `'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'` but requests is usually very good at defining it for you

Comment: Sorry for the delay, let me give it a try and i will update you

Comment: Based on your input, i modified the code but i'm still getting the same response

Comment: Do you believe, is it to do something with 'MultipartEncoder'?

Comment: Make sure image.png is referenced correctly, try to use the absolute path.  You can also use the program "insomnia" to try out the calls and see how the server responds with both `curl` and requests